# How to eliminate edge pixels on a plane?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I have a simple plane mesh, and am applying a texture to it. While the texture is stretched across the surface, just like I want it to, there appear to be some pixels around the edge that I can deal with in three ways:

1. Repeat (take the pixel values from the other side of the texture)
2. Clip (make those pixels transparent)
3. Extend (take the pixel values from the previous line)

But what can I do if I don't want these edge pixels at all - if I just want the texture to stretch across the entire surface? I've found a workaround through very careful UV editing, removing one line of pixels. But I think there *has* to be a better way. What am I missing?

**Edit:** Here are some pictures!

The texture:

[image]

How it looks when I apply that texture to a Plane in Blender:

[image]

The red and yellow line are both 1px, but when applied to the plane, it looks like the yellow one is thicker. More importantly though, there's a line of red pixels both to the right and on the bottom, which is not there in the original texture. For some reason, the texture seems to be repeating, when I want it to stretch across the plane. As I wrote above, the texture settings *extent* and *clip* don' t seem to be entirely what I want either. I just want the texture to fill up the entire plane, without any edge pixels that would have to be repeated, extended or clipped.

Comment: can u pls add some screenshots to make it clear what you have and what you want to have? thx

Comment: @Chris Yeah good point - added some!

Comment: did u try these settings? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3801.png

Comment: Oh, it seems _closest_ interpolation does exactly what I want! Can't say I understand what's going on there though. Now I have the detail problem that this setting seems to be ignored by Godot when exporting/importing as gltf, but that seems quite out of scope here.

Comment: I'm confused. 
It sounds like you want to just apply the texture without the border around it.
If so, why don't you simply crop the imageand use it without the border?
Do i understand this wrong?

Comment: @maddes8cht No, the border is just to illustrate what's happening. I basically just want to apply the texture as-is on a plane. It seems like _closest_ interpolation does what I want, but I'm still genuinely confused about whether this is the correct way to do that. It sounds simpler than it is for sure :D